# Angular2 - Data-Driven approach for radio button

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to use radio button in a form using Angular 2 with data-driven approach.
In my component, i create a form like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'forms-data-driven',
    templateUrl: 'data-driven.component.html'
})
export class DataDrivenComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  genders = ['male', 'female'];

  constructor() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl('Jam', Validators.required),
        'email': new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")]),
      }),
      'password': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'gender': new FormControl('male'),
    });
  }

  onSubmitted() {
    console.log(this.myForm);
  }
}
```

and in the html code :

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let g of genders">
        <label>
          <input type="radio"
                  formGroupName="gender"
                  [value]="g"
                  >
          {{g}}
        </label>
    </div>
```

the problem is that both radio buttons can be clicked at time.
any idea ?

Comment: I believe if you give each radio button the same name (name="gender"), then you can only chose one at a time.

Comment: thanks a lot. And for get the male gender checked i add [checked]="i===0" in the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `formGroupName`. Just give them the same name as `gender` and use the same `formControlName`. For the `gender` form control you will get the appropriate selected one.

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let g of genders">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" formControlName="gender" [value]="g">                
            {{g}}
        </label>
</div>
```

Every form control has it's [**ControlValueAccessor**](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).

Radio's have their own [**RadioControlValueAccessor**](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor), which do the logic for checking only one radio.